# Xcode will not open the ViewController.swift source files

Tags: xcode

I am in the `Xcode` editor. I can view the `Main.storyboard` or edit *most* of the source files. But for some reason the `[*]ViewController.swift` files will not display in the Editor section. What is going on?

The screenshot below shows that after hitting "enter" on the `SecondViewController.swift` instead of opening it in the editor the `experiments.js` remains. The same thing happens for `SecondViewController.swift`. However other `.swift` files do open properly.

I had edited those `*Controller` files in the past so this is bizarre.  Any tips?

[image]

Comment: See how the icons are dimmed compared to experiments.swift. Usually means the files don’t exist where Xcode thinks they are. Check the path in the Right hand document inspector.

Comment: Well now that you mention it ..  So what does that mean?

Comment: Sorry , hit return. Check the path and see if the files exist in the relevant folder.  You might need to assert the path using the widget in the document inspector or just re-add the files.

Comment: After you added the second part of your first comment I got it. Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe how the icons are dimmed in the two ViewController files compared to experiments.swift

This usually means that the files are not where Xcode thinks they are. Check the path in the Document inspector and if needed use the widget in the inspector to correct the path or you can add the files again from their current location.

Maybe you moved the files outside of Xcode during organising or refactoring to cause this.